# How to change struct tags by generics

Tags: go, generics

I need to create struct with generics with dynamic tags

> e.g. We have one struct with generics `Phone[T]` and simple struct `Company`

So Phone can belongs to Company and that means our type would be `Phone[Company]`

```golang
type Company struct{}

type Phone[T any] struct{
   number string `json:"phone_number"`
}
```

#### Lets create new variable `Phone[Company]`

```golang
phone1 := Phone[Company]{
   number: "+18888888888"
}
```

#### Output of serialized `phone1` is

```json
{
   "phone_number": "+18888888888"
}
```

## Question

How to set struct `Phone[T]` type field tags dynamically to receive json like `company_phone_number` instead of `phone_number`?

How can i use generic types in golang tags?

e.g.

```golang
type Phone[T any] struct{
   number string `json:"${T or replica name of T type e.t.c}_phone_number"`
}
```

Comment: You cannot, that0s not how generics work. Consider redesigning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it only if you rebuild your struct on-the-fly with reflect. There is a package for this (I didn't try it) [here](https://github.com/sevlyar/retag).

But instead I recommend you to write a custom MarshalJSON method for the struct which handles the cases based on the type of the variable.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type Phone[T any] struct {
    variableType T
    Number       string
}

func (p Phone[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    switch any(p.variableType).(type) {
    case Company:
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            Number string `json:"company_phone_number"`
        }{
            Number: p.Number,
        })
    case Company2:
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            Number string `json:"company2_phone_number"`
        }{
            Number: p.Number,
        })
    }
    return []byte{}, errors.New("Invalid type")
}

type Company struct {
}

type Company2 struct {
}

func main() {
    p := Phone[Company]{
        Number: "123",
    }

    p2 := Phone[Company2]{
        Number: "321",
    }

    data1, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    data2, _ := json.Marshal(p2)
    fmt.Println(p, string(data1))
    fmt.Println(p2, string(data2))
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qt7sta_4wTk)

If you want to avoid the switch you can get the variable type with `reflect.TypeOf(p.variableType).Name()` but then you have to write a custom JSON marshaler to represent the byte slice with the custom json tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible!

For your case you can redesign your architecture

Comment: You could have been more clear with docs. This answer is more kind of a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).